# JavaScript function problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I can't get this to display an alert fed as a function argument. I have compared to examples and can't see the problem causing it not to work. I have included my html and JavaScript below, any help in where I'm going wrong will be very gratefully received. Thanks A

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="testjs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "testbed">
<a id = "testlink" href = "#number1">Test click</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.fn.newmodalcontrols = function(modelspec) {
alert(modelspec);       
} // end newmodalcontrols

$('#testlink').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().newmodelcontrols('number1');
}); // end testlink click function

}); // end ready
```

Comment: Any errors reported in your JavaScript console (`F12` in most browsers)?

Comment: Yes it says the following...Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'newmodelcontrols' testjs.js:10
(anonymous function) testjs.js:10
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3074
elemData.handle

Comment: please check that testjs.js is loading properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a typo. Change newmodelcontrols to newmodalcontrols.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.fn.newmodalcontrols = function (modelspec) {
        alert(modelspec);
    }

    $('#testlink').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().newmodalcontrols('number1');
    });

});
```

**Update:** added a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gmWax/1/).

Comment: Haha that took hours of faffing around, feel silly now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: `newmodalcontrols` and `newmodelcontrols` are not equivalent (note the `a`/`e`): [corrected the typo, in a JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QUrAe/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.fn.newmodalcontrols = function (modelspec) {
        alert(modelspec);
    } // end newmodalcontrols
      //           ^- Should be an 'e'

    $('#testlink').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().newmodelcontrols('number1');
        //                     ^- Or this should be an 'a'
    }); // end testlink click function

}); // end ready
```

Incidentally, in Chromium, this would have been shown in the Web Inspector's JavaScript console as:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'newmodelcontrols'
```

Which should have drawn your attention to the name of the method you were using/defining.

Comment: Thank you for your help, problem solved and lesson learned. A

Comment: @Ant: no problem at all, I'm glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 0):

You got a typo.

Check out fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/AUEZJ/

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$.fn.newmodelcontrols = function (modelspec) {
    alert(modelspec);
}; // end newmodalcontrols


$('#testlink').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().newmodelcontrols('number1');
}); // end testlink click function
```

}); // end ready